# Unable to perform execve syscall in RISC V assembly

Tags: c, assembly, system-calls, riscv

I am trying to perform the execve syscall via assembly. Before I start, I have downloaded the riscv toolchain from the github repo, and configured it using: `./configure /opt/rv32./configure --prefix=/opt/rv32 --with-arch=rv32ia --with-abi=ilp32`.
In order to execute the binaries, I'm using qemu-user (`qemu-riscv32`).
Ok, so first I wrote a simple C program that performs an execve syscall. The code is the following:

```
#include <unistd.h>

char *args[] = {"/bin/sh", 0x0};

int main()
{
    execve(args[0], args, 0x0);
}
```

Then I dissassembled the produced code, and what I obtained is:

```
00010530 <main>:
   10530:   ff010113            addi    sp,sp,-16
   10534:   00112623            sw  ra,12(sp)
   10538:   00812423            sw  s0,8(sp)
   1053c:   01010413            addi    s0,sp,16
   10540:   a9418793            addi    a5,gp,-1388 # 85df0 <args>
   10544:   0007a703            lw  a4,0(a5)
   10548:   00000613            li  a2,0
   1054c:   a9418593            addi    a1,gp,-1388 # 85df0 <args>
   10550:   00070513            mv  a0,a4
   10554:   304160ef            jal ra,26858 <__execve>
   10558:   00000793            li  a5,0
   1055c:   00078513            mv  a0,a5
   10560:   00c12083            lw  ra,12(sp)
   10564:   00812403            lw  s0,8(sp)
   10568:   01010113            addi    sp,sp,16
   1056c:   00008067            ret

00026858 <__execve>:
   26858:   0dd00893            li  a7,221
   2685c:   00000073            ecall
   26860:   fffff8b7            lui a7,0xfffff
   26864:   00a8e463            bltu    a7,a0,2686c <__execve+0x14>
   26868:   00008067            ret
   2686c:   71d0406f            j   2b788 <__syscall_error>
   26870:   00008067            ret
```

Notice that the code has been compiled using `-static` flag

Then I tried to write my assembly program that basically does the same, so I ended up with the following code:

```
.globl _start
.section .text

_start:
    # execve syscall
    la a0, shell # Pointer to '/bin/sh'
    la a1, addr # Pointer to the arraythat contains '/bin/sh'
    sw a0, 0(a1)
    mv a2, x0 # No environment variables are needed
    li a7, 0xDD # 221
    ecall
    # exit syscall
    li a7, 0x5D # 93
    ecall

.section .rodata
shell: .string "/bin/sh"
.section .data
addr: .space 4
```

Then, I compiled the code with the following statement: `riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -c syscall.s && riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-ld syscall.o -o syscall`
And now, when I try to execute my C code, it works perfectly, even compiling the code without `-static` flag, but when I execute my assembly code it returns 242 as error code. Before that, I have been checking errno codes produced by a failed execve, but i found nothing.
In addition, I have been searching if someone has experienced the same problem but unfortunately anyone has.
Any idea? Is there something am I missing or am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `a1` (the second argument) needs to be a pointer to an array of pointers to strings.  But you're using a pointer (directly) to a string.

Comment: That's right, but the way you have seen in my code is the way I figured out was the correct (obviously was not). Thx

Comment: You know this would need major change to work as *shellcode*, right?  (i.e. bytes that could be injected via a `strcpy` vulnerability or something).  That would require the all the code+data to be contiguous, not in other sections, so normally you'd use stack space.  And to make it usable as a payload for most exploits, you'd need to avoid `00` bytes in the machine code, so you'd probably need to use  `sw a0, -1(a1)` or something as a store, to avoid a zero byte in the 12-bit offset of a load/store instruction.  (IIRC, the top 8 bits of that field are in a byte by themselves the machine code)

Comment: Yes, I know that writing a shellcode would require a more sophisticated way to deal with 0x00 bytes, but this exercise isn't part of a shellcode building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling the kernel how many entries there are in the argv array.  The rule is that argv needs to be an array of pointers *whose last entry is a NULL pointer*.  This would also be true for the envp argument if you were supplying an envp.

I'd suggest you do this with a preinitialized array also in `.rodata`, like so:

```
    .section .rodata
shell:
    .string "/bin/sh"
    .balign 4
argv:
    .4byte shell
    .4byte 0
```

and then your code can be something like

```
    .section .text
    .globl _start
    .type _start, @function
_start:
    # execve syscall
    la a0, shell # Pointer to '/bin/sh'
    la a1, addr  # Pointer to the array that contains '/bin/sh'
    li a2, 0     # No environment variables
    li a7, 0xDD  # 221 = execve
    ecall
    # _exit syscall
    # if execve returns, it failed, so pass 1 to _exit
    li a0, 1
    li a7, 0x5D  # 93 = _exit
    ecall
```

Comment: @Josep: You *can* pass an empty `argv[]` as well; most shells handle that corner case of argc=0, argv[0]=NULL.  And since this is Linux, `execve("/bin/sh", NULL, NULL)` is treated the same as passing valid pointers to NULL pointers `execve("/bin/sh", {NULL}, {NULL} );` (Not quite valid C syntax, you might actually do `char*tmp=NULL;` and then pass  `&tmp`.)  You're already taking advantage of that for envp, which is typical for shellcode, although it's a useful exercise in understanding asm, C, and the system call man pages, to generate one of these arrays the proper way.

Comment: Since a few days ago, I was using the aproach of execve("/bin/sh", NULL, NULL) and it was working for me. But the other day it stop working, so I decided to write like the decompiled C code showed above